# InternetExplorer | IE.au3 get all the cookies of a session

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, session-cookies, autoit, winhttp

I tried to create a automated login for a page. I wanted to login with InternetExplorer and give the session to a WinHTTP-Request to work with it.
To do that I need all the cookies but I only get a few. Here is an example:

[The cookies chrome shows me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vuMU.png)
[The cookies my script shows me.](http://img.ctrlv.in/img/14/10/17/54411d7968122.png)
And this is the function I use to get the cookies:

```
Func _IEGetCookies(ByRef $oIE)
    Return $oIE.document.cookie
EndFunc   ;==>_IEGetCookies
```

I think the problem is that the function only get local cookies and the others are like in the chrome screenshot "HTTP" but I don't know what HTTP-Cookies are and how to get them with AutoIt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to get the cookie with HttpOnly Tag.

When your cookie is with the HttpOnly flag, it tells the browser that this particular cookie should only be accessed by the server. Any attempt to access the cookie from client script is strictly forbidden.

Read this article for more informations:

http://blog.codinghorror.com/protecting-your-cookies-httponly/